# CorePlot, change number of tick marks on x-axis (to avoid an overabundance of tick marks)

Tags: xcode, graph, core-plot

My plot range is 160.5, and the graphing result has 2 large horizontal lines...which are actually just the tick marks and tick mark names squashed together 160 some-odd times to give the appearance of 2 large lines.

I am wondering how to change the major tick marks so that there's maybe 4-5  even ticks between the length of the x-axis.

I've attached a picture of the situation and put some code below (if that helps....or you need more info, I'll provide it.) I'm using XCode 9.2 with iOS 11.2.

[image: Graph image]

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) CPTGraph *graph;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong, nonnull) CPTMutableNumberArray *plotData;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) CPTScatterPlot* plot;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize plotData;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.graphView.bounds];
    [self.graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTSlateTheme]];

    self.graphView.hostedGraph = self.graph;

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;

    [plotSpace setYRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-2.0) length:@(6.00)]];
    [plotSpace setXRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-30.5) length:@(160.5)]];

    self.plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:self.graphView.frame];

    self.plot.dataSource = self;

    [self.graph addPlot:self.plot toPlotSpace:self.graph.defaultPlotSpace];

}

// bunch of other methods

@end
```

Comment: So to add on to this, if I change the x-axis length from 160.5 to 10.5, the tick marks and tick mark values appear on the axis. This tells me that each tick mark between -10.5 and 160.5 was generated, creating the illusion of 2 large horizontal lines.  Still no luck in finding where the source of the problem is, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone out there, change the Source Files directly (the folders under the CorePlot.xcodeproj drop-down option).  Specifically, I changed some parameters in the Stocks Theme x-axis object.

Answer (score 0):

The default labeling policy puts a major tick mark and label on each unit, so you're trying to squeeze 160 labels into a very small space. You need to adjust the labeling properties for the x-axis. You'll need to use some combination of the `labelingPolicy`, `preferredNumberOfMajorTicks`, and/or `minorTicksPerInterval` depending on the appearance you want.